# ClassNotFoundException vssver2

Tags: java, hibernate, visual-sourcesafe, catalina

i have a project, that uses vss.
lately i added hibernate to it
it works perfect locally, but when i run it on a tomcat server, on a remote server, after getting the project from vss, i get an exception when i run it:

ClassNotFoundException co.il.discountbank.entities.sybase.vssver2
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass (webbappClassLoaderBase.jave:1309)

co.il.discountbank.entities.sybase is the package i put my hibernate entities.
vssver2 is not part of my project...
any help?

Comment: If you search "vssver2" in the all project, do you have any found? Not just files. Searching any caller.

Comment: Your post is not a bad question, but at the same time, it is a question that's hard to read, understand and answer. There is little information as to the context of your problem and it is unlikely that someone will sit and stare at this for more than 30 seconds. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in order to improve your question quality and get good solutions by other community members.